# Closing a JavaScript window with an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have to make a JavaScript that opens a new Window, and then you need to be able to close it again with a click inside the window.
But my code does not work, could someone please provide me an answer to how this is done best?

```
function swipe() {
   var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
   var url = largeImage.getAttribute('src');
   var w = largeImage.naturalWidth;
   var h = largeImage.naturalHeight;   

   window.open(url,"Image", "height="+ h +", width="+ w +", resizable=yes");

   var myWindow = window.self;

   myWindow.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

   var elementIsClicked = false;

   function clickHandler(){ 
    elementIsClicked = true
   }

   function isElementClicked (){
    if(elementIsClicked){
            newWindow.close();
    }
   }

   setInterval(isElementClicked, 500);


}
```

Comment: You've not set `newWindow` anywhere, did you mean `var newWindow = window.open(...`?

Comment: _"and then you need to be able to close it again with a click inside the window"_ Click at original `window` or newly opened `window` should close opened `window` ?

Comment: I want to close the popup by clicking inside the newly opened window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.
Here is the solution to my problem:

```
  function swipe() {
   var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
   var url = largeImage.getAttribute('src');
   var w = largeImage.naturalWidth;
   var h = largeImage.naturalHeight; 

   var popup = window.open(url,"Image", "height="+ h +", width="+ w +", resizable=yes");


   popup.document.write('<img src="women_running_small.jpg" id="largeImage" style="width:95% ;height:95%; object-fit:contain"/>');
   popup.onclick = function() {
     // close `popup`
     popup.document.write("<script>this.close()<\/script>");
     // remove `onclick` handler
     this.onclick = null;
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

A comment says that `newWindow` is not defined anywhere. I think you meant to use the `myWindow` object. `myWindow.close()` will work, since it closes the window.

If you want to execute this when this first loads, you should put this in a `window.onload` function or a self-invoking function. Also, for full compatibility within all browsers, you should omit the `resizable=yes` part, because that is supported in only IE.

Also, if you want to use jQuery, you can execute this method within an `$(window).load()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `document.write()`

```
window.onload = function() {
   var largeImage = document.getElementById("largeImage");
   // var url = largeImage.getAttribute('src');
   var w = largeImage.naturalWidth;
   var h = largeImage.naturalHeight; 
   // open blank `window`
   var popup = window.open("", "Image"
                          , "height="+ h 
                            +", width="+ w 
                            +", resizable=yes");
   // write `img` `outerHTML` to `popup` `window`
   popup.document.write(largeImage.outerHTML);
   window.onclick = function() {
     // close `popup`
     popup.document.write("<script>this.close()<\/script>");
     // remove `onclick` handler
     this.onclick = null;
   }
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/0KUPw3UlEF0ONO1vDoOU?p=preview

Comment: This allowes me to close the popup when I click inside the popup, BUT the whole popup window is no longer in the right format. It does not open with height = h and width = w anymore.

Comment: @Vulkanos _"BUT the whole popup window is no longer in the right format. It does not open with height = h and width = w anymore"_ This was due to image from lorempixel not loading. See http://plnkr.co/edit/xZxZAp6W8z0UkWYYKXha?p=preview

Comment: @Vulkanos Alternatively, version 3 of plnkr closes opened `window` at `click` of newly opened `window` http://plnkr.co/edit/xZxZAp6W8z0UkWYYKXha?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newWindow;

function windowOpener() {
  var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387144/closing-a-javascript-window-with-an-onclick-event";
  newWindow = window.open(url, "Popup", "width=700,height=500");
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (newWindow.closed) {
      alert("window closed");
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 250)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="windowOpener();">Open a window</button>
```

Here is the code for opening and detecting whenever it closes.

Here is the sample code on codepen.io http://codepen.io/sujeetkrjaiswal/pen/vGebqy

The code is not runnig in the stackoverflow for some reason, try it on codepen.